# Sorting specific columns after concatenating data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I concatenated 3 dataframes into one dataframe. Now I want to sort some specific columns, so I used this code:

```
final_df.sort_values(['Tab1_1', 'Tab2_2'], ascending=False)
```

However, the output shows the values in `col1` ordered, but the values in `col5` aren't. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Here is an example of data:

```
concat_table = {'ID': ['Sun_1'], 
                'Tab1': ['Al', 'Alu', 'Alt'],
                'Tab1_1': [6, 3, 4], 
                '%_Tab_1': [90, 50, 40], 
                'Tab2': ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'], 
                'Tab2_2': [4, 5, 2],
                '%_Tab1_2': [60, 90, 40]}
```

This is how it should be ordered:

```
concat_table_ordered = {'ID': ['Sun_1'], 
                        'Tab1': ['Al', 'Alt', 'Alu'],
                        'Tab1_1': [6, 4, 3], 
                        '%_Tab_1': [90, 40, 50], 
                        'Tab2': ['Type2', 'Type1', 'Type3'], 
                        'Tab2_2': [5, 4, 2],
                        '%_Tab1_2': [90, 60, 40]}
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Onne idea, do you assign back like `final_df = final_df.sort_values(['col1','col5'], ascending=False)` ?

Comment: I tryed that, and It didn't changed...

Comment: So here is sorted what columns?

Comment: I want to sort column Tab1_1 and Tab2_2. First, I tried to sort table 1, wich are columns ( Tab1,Tab1_1,%_Tab_1)  and did the same to the remaining columns. However when I concatenate this two data frames, the order remained the same as the order before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sorting in pandas by multiple columns it sorts `sequentially`, it means first by first column in list, hers `Tab1_1` and then by next values, but only if duplicated values in previous columns, here `Tab1_1`:

```
concat_table={'ID':'Sun_1', 
              'Tab1': ['Al','Alu','Alt', 'aaa'],
              'Tab1_1':[6,3,4,4], 
              '%_Tab_1':[90,50,40,100],
              'Tab2':['Type1','Type2','Type3','Type4'],
              'Tab2_2':[4,5,2,1],
              '%_Tab1_2':[60,90,40,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame (concat_table)
print (df)
      ID Tab1  Tab1_1  %_Tab_1   Tab2  Tab2_2  %_Tab1_2
0  Sun_1   Al       6       90  Type1       4        60
1  Sun_1  Alu       3       50  Type2       5        90 <-4 are duplicated
2  Sun_1  Alt       4       40  Type3       2        40 <-4 are duplicated
3  Sun_1  aaa       4      100  Type4       1        20

df1 = df.sort_values(['Tab1_1','Tab2_2'], ascending=False)
print (df1)
      ID Tab1  Tab1_1  %_Tab_1   Tab2  Tab2_2  %_Tab1_2
0  Sun_1   Al       6       90  Type1       4        60
2  Sun_1  Alt       4       40  Type3       2        40 <-sorted 2,1 
3  Sun_1  aaa       4      100  Type4       1        20 <-sorted 2,1 
1  Sun_1  Alu       3       50  Type2       5        90
```

If need sorting separately is necessary split columns first, sorting and then assign back, but is necessary default index values by `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :4].sort_values(['Tab1_1'], ascending=False)
df2 = df.iloc[:, 4:].sort_values(['Tab2_2'], ascending=False)

final_df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), 
                      df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
print (final_df)
      ID Tab1  Tab1_1  %_Tab_1   Tab2  Tab2_2  %_Tab1_2
0  Sun_1   Al       6       90  Type2       5        90
1  Sun_1  Alt       4       40  Type1       4        60
2  Sun_1  Alu       3       50  Type3       2        40
```

Comment: This answered my question, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning this output to another df? Otherwise use `inplace=True`:

```
final_df.sort_values(['col1','col5'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: In this way, the result didn't change the order of the table

Comment: You used `inplace=True` ?

Comment: If yes, then what are the datatypes of the columns? It has to work.

Comment: Yes I used inplace=True. The columns I want to order are the first int and the second float... Should I change it to int?

Comment: @Sofia - `inplace=True` not help here, added answer with explain